# How to retrieve and display values in GridView from SQL Server database in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am creating a web application in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. I want to retrieve data from a SQL Server database and display it in a GridView in ASP.NET using C#.

I want to retrieve data on button onclick event.

protected void submit_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

connection1.open();

SqlCommand sq= new SqlCommand("select student_id
, student_name from student);

SqlDataReader dr= new SqlDataReader();

...

// Gridview

}

Comment: Hi. I am sure there are plenty of examples about this topic. Just try one first, then if you get any blocker, share it in here.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please try to format your code properly when you ask.  See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361) for help on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer for description : [Microsoft Visual Studio-how-to-retrieve-and-display-values-from-database-in -ASP.NET-using-C#.](https://pieceofcodes.blogspot.com/2020/06/how-to-retrieve-and-display-data-from.html)

> **protected** void **Button1_Click**( object sender, EventArgs e) {
>
> //connection string
>
> **SqlConnection con** = new **SqlConnection**("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
> AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\HP\Documents\Visual Studio
> 2010\Projects
> \assignment\assignment\App_Data\pokedex.mdf';Integrated
> Security=True; User Instance=True");
>
> con.Open();
>
> **SqlCommand** cmd = new **SqlCommand**("Select * from pokedex;");
>
> **SqlDataAdapter** sda = new **SqlDataAdapter**(cmd);
>
> **DataTable** dt = new **DataTable**();
>
> sda.Fill(dt);
>
> GridView1.DataSource = dt;
>
> GridView1.DataBind();
>
> con.Close();
>
> }